# JAX-WS throws SOAPFaultException Unauthorized

Tags: jax-ws

I've just set up a new JAX-WS client and when I run it, I'm getting the error 'java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unauthorized'

I've provided the correct username and password to login to the service as I have tested with SOAPUI. Could it be some kind of network/firewall issue in our company that would cause this?

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unauthorized
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.CompletedFuture.get(Unknown Source)
        at dacalcserviceclient.DACALCSERVICEClient$1.handleResponse(DACALCSERVICEClient.java:104)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.AsyncResponseImpl.set(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.AsyncMethodHandler$SEIAsyncInvoker$1.onCompletion(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub$1.onCompletion(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.completionCheck(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unauthorized
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: No, I did not configure any SSH settings in SOAP UI. And yes, I can access the WSDL on the server that I'm testing on.

Comment: What framework (if any) are you using to access the SOAP service?  Could you put several lines from your stack trace here?

Comment: I've just added my stacktrace. Interestingly, I ran the client on my computer, which has less internet restrictions, and I don't get that error.
I do however, get the error java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.UnknownHostException:

Comment: You never answered my question about the framework, but this sounds to me like there is a problem with your SOAP stub.  This would explain why it works with SOAP UI, but not from your Java code.

Comment: Sorry. No framework. I created a basic java app in neatbeans then added a web service client.

Comment: I'm fairly confident that your code is not talking to the service correctly.  Please check this.

Comment: This is my first ever web service client. How can I see what my SOAP stub looks like in java?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75993/discussion-between-tim-biegeleisen-and-user1024941).

Comment: Would love to, but I'm blocked from it on my work computer.